# AWS auto scaling Warm Pool instances do not run usre-data script if launched into Stopped state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have an auto-scaling group (ASG) on AWS. The EC2 instances in the ASG run a user-data bash script when they launch. I am using terraform and their [aws_autoscaling_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group) resource as my API.

I am now trying to add a warm pool to the ASG (`warm_pool` block in the API). I have a problem with the user-data script on the warm pool instances:

- When warm pool instances launch into `Stopped` state, they do not run the bash script. When these instances are re-started and transitioned into the ASG, they do not run the bash script either.
- When warm pool instances launch into `Running` state, they execute the user data bash script, and everything is fine

What could be the problem? I would like warm pool instances launching into the `Stopped` state to run the bash script before they are shut down.

In [this tutorial from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scaling-your-applications-faster-with-ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools/) they do exactly that. They run the user-data script on the warm pool instance before the instances are shut down. I am working to understand the difference between their CloudFormation [set up](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ec2-auto-scaling-group-examples/blob/main/features/lifecycle-hooks/userdata-managed-linux/template.yaml) and what I do, but on the surface it looks very similar. It looks like they are using a custom life cycle hook, but I am not sure if the hook controls the execution of user-data, or if it's the user-data script controlling the state of the hook.

Comment: Can you provide your userdata script. For the user data script to run always it needs to have multipart mime type and to have the below  #cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

Comment: @VikramS This might be it. My script is just a plain bash script without any additional configs. I will research the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by Vikram S, I had to use a MIME-formatted script with a config that ensures user script is always ran.

```yaml
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
  - [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="script.sh"

#!/bin/bash
touch /home/ec2-user/text
echo "Hello World" >> /home/ec2-user/text
--//
```